# Delete object by attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have a few different tables on the same page but unfortunately they were not assigned any unique id's. I want to remove a table using a JS command, but since id cannot be used, is it possible to delete a table based on a certain attribute it has? For example, is there a command to delete all tables on the page that have the attribute: width="25%" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this already has some solutions, but I'll offer up one more alternative.

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
    if(tables[i].getAttribute('width') == "25%"){
        tables[i].parentNode.removeChild(tables[i]);
    }
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/michaelehead/pen/HfdKx.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to use this instead, since in my case i was running the JS commands through an android webview which apparently doesnt support querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to do that.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("table[width='25%']");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { //returns array of elements that match the attribute selector
    x[i].remove(); //call prototype method defined below
}
```

Removing is tricky, I found this code that makes a nice remove method

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a prototype `remove()` function that iterates the node and deletes the children.

Please note that `querySelectorAll` will not work in IE8 or below, but the poster of the prototype method said that it should work in IE8 but not 7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The easiest way is to use JQuery.
In your javascript code you would just write:

```
$("[attribute=value]").remove()
```

So in your case it could be something like `$("table[width='25%']").remove()`

Comment: Absolutely works, but he didn't ask for a jQuery answer.

Comment: Agreed. Just trying to be helpful.